# Как реализовать добавление чекбоксов на форму при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет.Мне нужно оформить добавление чекбоксов на форму при нажатии на кнопку но я не понимаю как сделать так чтобы они появлялись ровно  под предыдущими текстбоксами.
Вот так я создаю новый текстбокс.

```
private void AddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Top = 100;
        textBox.Left = 20;

        Controls.Add(textBox);
    }
```

Comment: Да, чтоб когда пользователь нажимает на копку создавался чекбокс

Comment: начните с `CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();`

Comment: А можно настроить чтобы он поясвлялся  под прошлим чекбоксом

Comment: Создайте форму с интересующим внешним видом в дизайнере, откройте файл <formName>.designer.cs и посмотрите как в коде настраиваются и добавляются элементы. После этого идете на MSDN и много читаете, примеров кода там много, WinForms - технология старая. Пробуете, ошибаетесь, перечитываете, пробуете еще раз. С фрагментом кода в котором не смогли разобраться сами или работает не так как ожидается приходите сюда, как следует описываете проблему, получаете ответ. В текущем виде на ваш вопрос можно дать не меньше десятка правильных или, хотя-бы, просто рабочих примеров, какой из них вам нужен?

Comment: мне бы хоть какой то пример того как это делается)

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/756850/edit), перенесите уточнения из комментария в вопрос. Там есть возможность форматировать код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз создавать контролы и добавлять их на форму научились, идем дальше.

Кроме функциональных контролов (Button, TextBox, CheckBox и т.д.), есть контролы контейнеры.

Если вам нужно просто автоматическое размещение контролов один под другим, можно воспользоваться стандартным контейнером [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx). Его понадобится немного настроить под вашу задачу, а именно свойства: `WrapContents = false`, `FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown`.

Теперь просто добавляйте ваши `CheckBox`-ы на эту панель, так же как добавляли на форму, они будут автоматически размещаться один под другим сверху вниз.

В общем-то у вас всегда был вариант вручную вычислять положение следующего контрола из координат (свойство Location) и размера (свойство Size) предыдущего контрола, но это обычно нужно, когда ни один из стандартных контейнеров не реализует нужного вам поведения.

Comment: Спасибо,я создал FlowLayoutPanel но не пойму как именно в ней создавать текстбоксы.

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov у любого контрола WinForms есть свойство Controls - коллекция дочерних контролов. Вы бы почитали про свойства FLP в документации внимательно, я даже прямую ссылку на писание оставил специально.

Comment: Я почему то не могу найти его в свойствах  FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov оно наследуется от типа Control, от этого типа наследуется все в WinForms, включая сами формы, его не может там не быть. Обращение вроде `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls`.

Comment: Никак не пойму как посмотреть контрол FLP.

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov в каком смысле посмотреть? добавьте его на форму. потом на него добавляйте элементы.

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229601(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Я кажись понял.
`flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textBox);`
Так будет правильно?

Comment: Заработало!Но у меня почему-то сразу добавляется 5 текстбоксов а при следубщих кликах по одному.

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov видимо вы их добавили в дизайнере. добавленное в дизайнере не удаляется само, надо руками или в дизайнере или в коде.

Comment: И вправду я был уже существующие перетащил на FLP.А как мне сделать так чтобы добавлять сразу несколько текст боксов в одной линии(1 широкий и 1 узкий)?